# How do I replace name1 and name2 with an input string in Python using escaping?

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and this challenge is difficult for me to figure out. I have to:
Pass in 2 strings, name1 and name2. You should output another string in the format

name1's done
and name2's done
with a new line between the two
and where name1 and name2 are replaced with the input string.

```
# Input from the command line
import sys
name1 = sys.argv[1]
name2 = sys.argv[2]

# Your code goes here
newString = 'sys.argv[1]\'s done\nand name2\'s done'
print(newString)
```

My error message:
Program Failed for Input: 1 2
Expected Output: 1's done
and 2's done
Your Program Output: sys.argv[1]'s done
and name2's done

Your output was incorrect.

Comment: `newString = "{}'s done \nand {}'s done".format(name1, name2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **format** to print this output:.

```
newString = '{}\'s done and {}\'s done'.format(name1, name2)
print(newString)
```

Comment: With a few edits, this worked! Thank you bhansa!!! Solution: newString = {}\'s done\nand {}\'s done".format (name1, name2)

Answer (score 0):

You may simple use `%s` as shown below

```
newString = '%s\'s done and %s\'s done' % (name1, name2)
```